# "Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined", Need a solution or alternative method to create a connection to the DB

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cosmosdb

This is the error that I'm facing

> System.UriFormatException: 'Invalid URI: The format of the URI could
>   not be determined.'

I have used IDocumentClient to create a connection to the DB

```
services.AddSingleton<IDocumentClient>(x => new DocumentClient(new Uri(Configuration["CosmosDB:URL"]), Configuration["CosmosDB:PrimaryKey"]));
```

Below given is my appsetings.json file from where the credentials are being acquired

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
    "CosmosDB": {
        "URL": "https://localhost:8081",
        "PrimaryKey": "C2y6yDjf5/R+ob0N8A7Cgv30VRDJIWEHLM+4QDU5DE2nQ9nDuVTqobD4b8mGGyPMbIZnqyMsEcaGQy67XIw/Jw=="
    },
  "DatabaseId": "FinanceProd"
}
```

Comment: Just to make sure, Configuration["CosmosDB:URL"] does return the localhost uri yeah?

Comment: I have try it, it's ok in my demo. Maybe you can update  package  version in your project.

Comment: I added the URL/PrimaryKey directly and it worked, I think it wasn't returning the uri which casuing errors

Comment: Yeah, I know, I try it. And your `Configuration["CosmosDB:URL"]` is also right. @AkshatGautam  Can you show me the version of your project package ?

Comment: This sounds like a problem on the Configuration package, can you share the CSPROJ you are using? Sometimes it boils down to using the wrong `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json` for the framework version (for example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

This problem is very strange, I tried to reduce the package version, but they all work normally. So I think the problem is not the package version.

Maybe you can debug your program with breakpoints. Like ,

```
string URL = Configuration["CosmosDB:URL"];
string PrimaryKey = Configuration["CosmosDB:PrimaryKey"];
services.AddSingleton<IDocumentClient>(x => new DocumentClient(new Uri(Configuration["CosmosDB:URL"]), Configuration["CosmosDB:PrimaryKey"]));
```

If the problem is not solved, there really is no better way to configure the parameters

**PRIVIOUS**

Your code is right, but now you face this issue. I guess it may be caused by the version of the package.

I have created a core app which db is in local and try it success.   My package version like bellow.

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos" Version="3.8.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core" Version="2.10.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

So I suggest you update the package version first. If this is not possible, I suggest that you recreate the demo for testing. Perhaps the other part of the code interfered.